# Custom glyph is not displayed properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, input-encodings

Recently I got the request to write a dissertation on the topic of quantum diagrammatic algebra. It was a fun LaTeX challenge as well, as there were plethora of custom glyphs I had to define in order to write the paper. For example, some of loops similar to ones in [Louis Kauffman's 1987 paper State models and the Jones polynomial](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kauffmanjones.pdf). At first my task seemed pretty plain. That was, until I compiled my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\begin{scope}
\clip (-1.5ex,0) rectangle (1.5ex,1.5ex);
\draw (0,0) circle(1.5ex);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
I love \verb|\foo| \foo{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the edges of my glyph are cut off, which displeases me greatly. I always valued beautiful documents and I want mine to be as good-looking as possible. To get the general idea of high-quality custom glyphs, take a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.4121.pdf) paper.

Please help me with this issue. To rehearse, I would like to know the best possible way of creating custom glyphs (so that they are compiled in their entirety). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**

I found out about the `knots` package. Have you tried it? It seems to produce *exactly* what you want. Type `texdoc knots` in the terminal for further info (or use CTAN)

**BACK TO THE QUESTION**

So, you have to extend the clipping area, in order to accomodate the line stroke.

I changed:

```
 \clip (-1.58ex,0.01) rectangle (1.6ex,1.6ex);
```

So:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\begin{scope}
\clip (-1.58ex,0.01) rectangle (1.6ex,1.6ex);
\draw (0,0) circle(1.5ex);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
I love \verb|\foo| \foo{}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: @GregorPerčič I added more info. Have you ever considered the `knots` package?

Comment: No, I didn't know about the `knots` package before. Thank you for telling me. My only concern is the compatibility; can `knots` be used to define glyphs as well (I'll find out sooner or later)?

Comment: @GregorPerčič I don't understand what you mean by "glyphs". But the whole `tikz` ensemble of packages (`knots` is one of them) surely can do something for you. You just need to find the right tools. I think knots is one of them

Comment: I was afraid that `knots` macros weren't compatible with commands such as `\newcommand`. When a clash between a package and a command happens, nasty things are bound to occur. I had a bad experience with such incompatibility once, and it wasn't pretty (7 hours of debugging got the best of me; then I finally realised the two just weren't compatible). I think a "sub"-package shouldn't cause problems. Thank you for your dedication.

Answer (score 10):

Why clipping? Just draw an arc!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\foo}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\draw (0,0) arc(180:0:1.5ex);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
I love \verb|\foo| \foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Minutes after I wrote the question I realised the `arc` would do the thing much better, without "fine-tuning" that is. I decided not to report on my discovery as I was hoping to get a package which would be specifically made for drawing braid diagrams. @Moriambar was of great help at this point, as he introduced me to two lovely packages: `knots` and `braids` (the latter was meant for `PGF2.10`, but it works fine on `3.0.1a` as well). With these two I don't have to use plain `tikz` anymore. Thank you for your care. LaTeX truly has a wonderful community!